# In Bash, the dirname command is not found

Tags: dirname

I'm writing a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$(readlink -f $0)
echo $PATH
DIR_PATH=$(dirname $PATH)
echo $DIR_PATH
```

However, the output is:

```
/home/kalyani/Desktop/Linux/Proj/script.sh
./script.sh:line 6: dirname: command not found
```

I checked every other solution available, and tried each one, and none of them worked. I've read the other threads on similar problems and it still doesn't work.

What could be the problem?

Also, if I type 'which dirname', I get /usr/bin/dirname.

If I echo $PATH, I get:

```
/home/kalyani/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin/:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Since /usr/bin is in my $PATH variable, it should be found, and it is found if I type it in the terminal, but if it's in a bash script, then it's giving me trouble. What can I do?

Comment: If all you are doing is trying to store the full path of the file (and not actively intending to reset your PATH system variable, which determines where to look for any command that doeasn't alreay have a full or relative path specified), then *use a different variable name*, and for goodness sake, STOP using names in all caps. Those are (by convention) "reserved" for the system. If you want to store it in `$path`, go ahead, that'll work fine and be safe, but using uppercase `$PATH` alters the way your environment works. Don't use caps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you execute

```
PATH=$(readlink -f $0)
```

Your PATH is now the name of the linked file, which is not a directory, so *nothing* is in your PATH anymore.

Use a different variable. If you are trying to make sure your path *includes* the location of the current file, the use

```
me="$(readlink -f ${BASH_SOURCE:-$0})"
PATH=$PATH:${me%/*}
```

If you aren't using bash,

```
me=`readlink -f "$0"`
PATH="$PATH:"`dirname $me`
```

or

```
PATH="$PATH:"`readlink -f "$0" | sed 's,/[^/]*$,,'`
```

Comment: In other words, assigning to the PATH variable in the script overrides your shell environment variable $PATH where all paths like `/usr/bin, /usr/sbin, ...` are set. A different variable name will solve it. Check https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html for internal variables.